# calculation concerning opacity

Tags: java

hi guys i have a kind of math problem

i have the following loop:

```
for(int i = 10; i < 150; i = i + 5)
{
    imageView.setBounds(
        ini.getMonsterX(monsterName) -i/2,
        ini.getMonsterY(monsterName) -i/2, 
        i, 
        i);
    imageView.repaint();
    imageView.setVisible(true);
    Log.e(TAG, "setSize = "+i );
    r.delay(10);
}
```

if i = 10 the opacity should be 1.0f
and if i = 150 the opacity should be 0.0f

how do i calculate the values in between?

Comment: I recommend you to avoid using "magic numbers", declare a `static final float` variable, and set its value as 150. (Same goes for other constants). It might help you refactor the code if you will later discover the constant should be different or a parameter. (Note: this does not solve your issue - just a general case tip)

Answer (score 3):

This is basic [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points):

```
opacity = (150f - i) / (150f - 10f)
```